# WCF WorkFlow Service

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am working on WCF WorkFlow Service Application. i have two ReceiveAndSendReply Activity in sequence. i have set CanCreateInstance to true in both the activities Now i am not able to access the second ReceiveAndSendReply Activity. i know this because its needs to be executed sequentially right ? then how can i create WCF service methods in such way that i can call any of the method anytime.i think that can be achieved by creating State Machine Workflow but how to create in WCF WorkFlow Please suggest me some best ways i can do this.

Comment: Why cant you use state machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put ReceiveAndSendReply  in a pick branch. You can have several branches with several ReceiveAndSendReply activities. But if you have more service calls to your workflow then the recommended way is to use state machine.

Comment: i am not finding any example for using state machine WCF workflow , do  u have nay link?

Comment: http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2012/03/workflow-foundation-4-state-machine-as.html Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parallel activity and add one branch for every receiveandSend activity and set its CanCreateInstance to true